# Spring REST Exception Handling JSON issue

Tags: java, json, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have create one global exception handler using `@controllerAdvice`. As i am using `@ResponseBody` and `jackson` jars for JSON to POJO and vice versa, It should return info in JSON but it is not returning me any json.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController{

@ExceptionHandler(EmployeeNotFoundException.class)
public @ResponseBody ExceptionJSONInfo handleEmployeeNotFoundException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex){

    ExceptionJSONInfo response = new ExceptionJSONInfo();
    response.setUrl(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    response.setMessage(ex.getMessage());

    return response;
    }
}
```

My Controller is as follows :

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/emp/{id}/view.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) throws Exception{
        //deliberately throwing different types of exception
        if(id==1){
            throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(id);
        }else if(id==2){
            throw new SQLException("SQLException, id="+id);
        }else if(id==3){
            throw new IOException("IOException, id="+id);
        }else if(id==10){
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.setName("Pankaj");
            emp.setId(id);
            model.addAttribute("employee", emp);
            return "home";
        }else {
            throw new Exception("Generic Exception, id="+id);
        }

    }
}
```

My conf.xml is as follow :

```
 <beans:bean id="simpleMappingExceptionResolver" class="com.journaldev.spring.resolver.MySimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="Exception" value="generic_error"></beans:entry>
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="defaultErrorView" value="generic_error"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>
```

Anybody can tell me where i going wrong. I am using Spring MVC 4 + AngularJS + Tomcat 8.

> if i use `@RequestMapping(value="/emp/{id}/view.htm"` it is not returning JSON but if i use `@RequestMapping(value="/emp/{id}"`like this it is retuning JSON. Why this happing?? My all url is end with .htm

Comment: @KarthikR `@RequestMapping` is not required in ControllerAdvice.

Comment: @SwapL are you sure your exception handler method is called?

Comment: @NamanGala Yes , I have checked it.

Comment: Is your REST controller throwing EmployeeNotFoundException ? Can you post the method that throws the exception?

Comment: Do you have entry for **jackson mapper** in your **pom.xml**?

Comment: @NamanGala i have added my controller. Yes jackson-mapper-asl.jar in my build path.

Comment: Is there any special requirement to add `MySimpleMappingExceptionResolver`,`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in your conf.xml?

Comment: @NamanGala not exactly.

Comment: Can you comment those entries in your `conf.xml` and test your code.

Comment: @NamanGala yes did that but not retruning JSON

Comment: @SwapL how did you check that it is not returning JSON?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89123/discussion-between-swap-l-and-naman-gala).